# Thread deletion problems in a TCP server using FreeRtos, netconn API and HAL libraries for stm32f2

Tags: c, stm32, tcpclient, freertos, lwip

I'm working on a custom board project that:

1. will connect PC hosts (client applications) to this board following the client-server model communication.
2. will receive request packets asking for data
3. writes/reads io microntroller pins status (mcu = stm32f207zg)
4. will send answers with data about these actions

The goal is to get a firmware version that implements a TCP server handling multiple client connections, up to 10, by the same application port.

First of all I have kept the demo project structure (it is said on the application notes that this structure is the correct way) [DemoApp_AN](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an3384-lwip-tcpip-stack-demonstration-for-stm32f2x7xx-microcontrollers-stmicroelectronics.pdf). And then I customized this thread adding the actions for answer sending (from the server to the client application). It works fine in "server - only one client" mode.

So, thinking about how to create multiclient thread I created another thread when every new connections arrives. I followed this scheme implementation:

**Server thread and client handle thread implementation (mine):**

```
/**extern global**/

extern uint8_t BWR_FLAG;
extern uint8_t SWR_FLAG;
extern uint8_t tcpBufferWRL[20];
extern uint8_t tcpBufferWRS[5];
extern uint8_t enableBlink[16];
extern uint8_t BytesRD[16];
extern uint8_t Length;
extern sPins gpio_inputs[MAX_IN_PINS];
extern sPins gpio_outputs[MAX_OUT_PINS];
extern sPins gpio_adr[MAX_ADR_PINS];
struct netif gnetif;

static void tcpecho_thread(void *arg)
{
    struct netconn *conn, *newconn;
    err_t err, accept_err;

    LWIP_UNUSED_ARG(arg);

    /* Create a new connection identifier. */
    conn = netconn_new(NETCONN_TCP);

    if (conn!=NULL)
    {
        /* Bind connection to well known port number 7. */
        err = netconn_bind(conn, NULL, 43808);//todo: magic number

        if (err == ERR_OK)
        {
            /* Tell connection to go into listening mode. */
            netconn_listen(conn);

            while (1)
            {
                /* Grab new connection. */
                accept_err = netconn_accept(conn, &newconn);

                /* Process the new connection. */
                if (accept_err == ERR_OK)
                {
                    // new connected client thread  
                    sys_thread_new("ActiveConn_thread", ActiveConn_thread, (void*)newconn, DEFAULT_THREAD_STACKSIZE, TCPECHO_THREAD_PRIO );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
          netconn_delete(newconn);
        }
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void tcpecho_init(void)
{
  sys_thread_new("tcpecho_thread", tcpecho_thread, NULL, DEFAULT_THREAD_STACKSIZE, TCPECHO_THREAD_PRIO );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

```
/*Here is the client thread with their actions once 
packet is received up to the answer and closing connection*/

static void ActiveConn_thread(void *arg)
{
    struct netconn *newconn = arg;
    struct netbuf *buf;
    void *data;

    u16_t len;
    uint8_t pp[20];
    uint8_t *buffer = NULL ;
    uint8_t nPin = 0;
    /* get new client connection reiceved buffer */
    while (netconn_recv(newconn, &buf) == ERR_OK) //buf = netbuf = packet buffer from netconn
    {
        do
        {
            netbuf_data(buf, &data, &len);//Get the data pointer and length of the data inside a netbuf = buf = paquet rebut.
            buffer = (uint8_t*)data;
            Length = len-1;

            //*get bytes
            for (uint8_t i = 0; i<=len;i++)
            {
                pp[i]=buffer[i];

            }
            if(pp[0] == 0xC1)
            {

              len = 16;
              for (uint8_t i = 0; i<len;i++)
              {

                  BytesRD[i] = ML_GPIO_GetState(gpio_inputs[i].tPort,gpio_inputs[i].tPin);
                  if (BytesRD[i] == 0) BytesRD[i] = 1;
                  else BytesRD[i] = 0;
              }

              /* answer*/
              data = (void*)BytesRD;
              netconn_write(newconn, data, len, NETCONN_COPY);
            }

        }

        while (netbuf_next(buf) >= 0);
        netbuf_delete(buf);

    }

    /* Close connection and discard connection identifier. */
    netconn_close(newconn);
    netconn_delete(newconn);

    vTaskDelete( NULL );
}
```

**Problems:**

This seems to work fine until number of clients reaches the value of 5, if a 6th client try to connect this server, the connection gets lost. The same happens when I disconnect the same client. When number of connections achieves this number, new thread client creation stops. So, no new client connections are done.

So looking for the problem I debugged **LwIP files** and I noticed these things:

- after the 6th connection execution is working as expected, until this statement is achieved:

```
while (netconn_recv(newconn, &buf) == ERR_OK) //buf = netbuf = packet buffer from netconn
```

- if I go inside, step by step mode, the netconn function (it can be found on the api_lib.c file) it returns an ERR_MEM
- there is another statement that returns this error code because this action returns a value = 0:

```
   buf = (struct netbuf *)memp_malloc(MEMP_NETBUF);
```

Seeing that, it seems that memory issues is the problem. It could be the result of wrong multiclient thread creation, bad task deletion, LwIP wrong configuration, etc.

So I proceeded to do some checking and I saw that server was unable to create more than 6 threads. It makes me suspect about Rtos issues. I realesed that maybe I need to increase memory heap on FreeRtosconfig file.

**Improvement attempts:**

I have also taken these actions:

- I ensured that I have freertos RAM writer enabled instead app writer.
- Then I increased heap size,
- so after this action, the number of client tasks that could be created by the server thread passed from 5 to 18.

It's an improvement, but the main problem stills unsolved: ****resource free action seems not to work with terminatetask(id) action if it's called in the same created thread**. I had understood that resources are automatically freed if terminate function was called when RTOS is configured with freeRtos writing on RAM.**I have seen that the project is compling heap_4.c file for memory management. But if we are unable to create new threads (unless heap size increases) it seems to be a non effective task deletion.

**Questions:**

If deletion task is not freeing the deleted thread's memory resources, does it need something else to be done before? How can it be done? I ask for suggestions or any related information.

---

***Post edition:***

According to comments I try to search what kind of memory management FreeRtos middleware has in my project and I saw this:

[image: compiled "memory management" freeRTOS file]

I guess this mean that project is using pvPortMalloc instead malloc. If I'm wrong please, let me know.

Comment: If you want tot use malloc style allocation it will never work. Use fixed size memory pools

Comment: @
0___________
 thanks for your answer. Could you explain me why it will never works? Since LwIP stack library offers the two options and demo is using malloc instead of pool mode and it works. Why to offer a tool that doesn't works? I guess you have seen a signal on my shared code that makes you say such this thing. Is it?

Comment: Have you redirected `malloc()` to `pvPortMalloc()` of FreeRTOS? Like this: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Hooks-for-Malloc.html

Comment: -i486 I will explain you the last think I have just checked: I ensured that I have freertos RAM writer enabled instead app writer. Then I increased heap size, so after this action, the number of tasks that could be created passed from 5 to 18. It's an improvement, but now the second problem, resource free action seems not to work with terminatetask(id) action if it's called in the same created thread. I had understood that resources are automatically freed if terminate function was called when RTOS is configured with freeRtos writing on RAM. Maybe I'm wrong. I will check what you say.

Comment: @i486 thanks for your comment. How can I check if this is done on the FreeRtos? is it at FreeRtosConfig.h file too?

Comment: @Suvi_Eu By default `malloc` is not hooked by FreeRTOS (at least in older versions - not sure for the latest). You can simply see the address range reserved for `pvPortMalloc` and address returned by `char * test = malloc(5);`

Comment: @i486 First question: what does it exactly mean: redirect malloc to pvPortMalloc()? Second qüestion: so, do you mean that depending on which value is returned I could see if freertos has redirected malloc to pvPortMalloc()?

Comment: @Suvi_Eu Follow the link above and read about `__malloc_hook`. In short - you will tell the compiler to call `pvPortMalloc` (FreeRTOS API) when program is calling `malloc()`.

Comment: Thanks. I asked you this, because I'm not calling malloc inside my threads implementation code. But I know LwIP does it, FreeRtos and CMSIS libraries maybe also does it. Did you mean that Is it a way for redirecting malloc at FreeRtos options? I'm not sure if I'm understanding you. Should I implement some functions as in your shared link? or is there a place for doing easily this redirection  in option/configuration files?

Comment: I said that because I found posts and suggestions saying things like these: "For pvPortMalloc, you can choose from various implementations in the FreeRTOS source code (heap1.c to heap4.c); look at the comments in front of the files to choose the one that fits best your needs." it seems freertos configuration options. I'm reading more literature in order to learn how choose this option. I hope to get it soon.

Comment: @i486 thanks, my project is compiling heap_4.c file. This file has pvPortMalloc functions. Is it enough to afirm that malloc is redirected to  pvPortMalloc? Should I do something else?

Comment: @Suvi_Eu `__free_hook` and `__realloc_hook` must be assigned too.

Comment: There is a vPortFree function that it is used by other FreeRtos files. I guess they are redirected too. The abstact of this file says this: "implementation of pvPortMalloc() and vPortFree() that combines (coalescences) adjacent memory blocks as they are freed, and in so doing limits memory fragmentation."

Comment: @Suvi_Eu did you manage to find a solution to this issue? I ran into the same issue with FreeRTOS on Xilinx FPGA. I can confirm that I have the same observation on my side regarding the number of attempts until FreeRTOS is not able to allocate new threads/tasks for newly accepted TCP connections.

Comment: @IoT no, I don't. Do you? My team mate has noticed that terminating the client thread from outside the thread is more effective than terminating from the client thread. I'm not sure if this has any logical base since resource freeing (and deleting a task) effectiveness depends on IDLE task execution, not about who is calling "deletetask". He has also created previously the number of client threads that will be our max number of allowed client connections. It seems that doing these 2 modifications is geting a behavior  improvement. We both still working on it.

Comment: @Suvi_Eu No unfortunately I did not have any progress. I can tell you in the Xilinx case when you create a template application for the TCP server in FreeRTOS. They do delete the thread within the thread itself. So it is interesting to know that your colleague observed improved behavior when terminating the thread outside its scope.

Comment: @IoT I'm afraid that this is not the normal behavior.. Reading FreeRtos information there is no reason for killing threads outside threads scope results in a better performance. We have no idea about why this way can free resources but not the other one. Nevertheless, our new improvement works during some work hours. Application stops with a hardfault on the worst case or losing the ping at the best case (mcu is not completely hanged). So, we still working on a better solution -with no success-.